# Backand on-demand action

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, backand

In my backand app, I have created an Action that should return a chain of objects. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I keep getting the 404 error:

```
Action not found, or is not on demand
```

While:

- The action does exist in my app
- The action is an on-demand action
- It used to work, until I started using the vanilla SDK (which seems to be the new standard at backand, correct me if I'm wrong)
- I simply copy-pasted the code that Backand provides when you create an action
- The 'Where' condition on the action is 'true', so it's not the condition holding me back

This is my code:

```
this.fetchUserFeed = function(userId) {
        return Backand.object.action.get("entities", "fetchUserFeed", {
          "parameters": {
            "user": userId
          }
        }).then(function(res) { console.log(res); }, handleError('Error fetching user feed'));
      }
```

Anyone an idea to what might cause this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, thanks for using Backand! Can you provide a couple more details?

- Do the object and action names match exactly?

- Have you tried using object.action.post? Does it face the same issue?

- Are there any security restrictions on the object that require you to be logged in?

- Are you accessing the action as an anonymous user, or after authentication?

You're correct in that the new Vanilla SDK is the recommended way to interact with Backand, but if you don't wish to upgrade you're of course free to construct the requests yourself using whichever pattern you like.

Comment: Hi @MattBillock, thanks for replying! I had to set some things straight before answering you.
1) The object and action name matched exactly. 2) I have tried using POST, this eventually did the job (read further) 3) There are no specific security restrictions on the object. 4) I was doing this with Anonymous user but currently switched to authenticating first.
Itay has also looked into this and told me that I had to remove "parameters" as well. So, using 'POST' instead of 'GET' _and_ removing "parameters" eventually solved my problem. Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: Cool, glad you were able to get this resolved!